# extremal index in r extremes package

Tags: r, independent-set

I want to confirm that the data is iid. I am investigating hourly precipitation data. The attached data is q99 of 7 gauges within a region and they should be iid by definition (I am taking a maximum number of one value/day).

I am using the "extremalindex" in the "extremes" package, yet the results are odd and showing a very low value, while it should be close to 1. The data is called group_c and the code is

```
tmp <- extremalindex(group_c$rainfall_in_mm  , 0, method="intervals", run.length=2, blocks=group_c$year)
```

can any one help me??? what is the problem in my code.

I chose a threshold of 0 because all the data should be included in further analysis (the data is Q99)

please find here the used data

gauge year month day hour rainfall_in_mm

```
A   1992    7   8   20  9.2
A   1992    9   2   15  18.4
A   1993    6   10  9   7.6
A   1993    7   15  20  8.2
A   1993    9   13  10  8.2
A   1994    7   24  19  10.4
A   1994    8   17  10  9.4
A   1995    2   22  15  7.6
A   1998    6   26  20  9.6
A   1998    9   9   10  11
A   1998    11  8   4   7.2
A   1998    11  14  8   8.6
A   1999    8   13  20  8.4
A   1999    8   19  5   10
A   2000    7   10  10  7.2
A   2000    7   29  15  31.2
A   2000    10  30  9   10.6
A   2001    3   3   10  7.4
A   2001    7   18  24  9.2
A   2002    9   9   14  9
A   2003    6   1   23  8.4
A   2003    6   27  22  7.4
A   2004    4   26  12  7.4
A   2004    6   21  16  8
A   2004    8   9   21  8.4
A   2005    6   19  17  27
A   2005    6   30  15  16.4
A   2005    7   28  19  9.6
A   2005    8   31  18  13
A   2006    8   19  15  11.4
A   2006    8   23  18  18.6
A   2006    9   2   13  9
A   2006    11  25  4   7.6
A   2006    12  30  2   8.2
A   2007    6   25  11  7.2
A   2008    8   1   4   13.8
A   2008    8   31  19  9.2
A   2008    9   6   4   9.8
A   2009    6   23  15  8
A   2009    6   27  15  10.6
A   2009    7   3   12  24.6
A   2009    7   7   10  9.2
A   2010    6   7   18  7.6
A   2010    10  3   14  14
B   1992    8   22  18  8
B   1993    9   8   6   9.2
B   1993    12  19  9   9.6
B   1994    7   6   22  9.6
B   1994    7   30  19  11.4
B   1994    10  22  19  9.2
B   1995    1   28  1   15
B   1996    7   29  15  10.2
B   1996    8   10  8   10.8
B   1996    8   26  15  8.6
B   1998    12  12  22  8
B   1999    5   7   19  7.6
B   1999    7   5   17  14.4
B   2000    4   23  19  9
B   2000    6   3   24  8.8
B   2000    6   4   3   9
B   2000    9   20  16  9.4
B   2000    10  30  18  9
B   2000    11  1   17  13.8
B   2000    11  2   20  7.6
B   2001    4   4   5   12.8
B   2001    9   27  14  9
B   2002    6   14  17  12.2
B   2004    8   9   13  19
B   2004    8   10  7   10.8
B   2004    8   17  14  12.4
B   2004    8   20  4   15.4
B   2004    10  2   13  7.6
B   2004    10  22  24  8.2
B   2005    4   26  18  7.6
B   2005    12  30  19  7.6
B   2006    5   21  21  9.4
B   2006    8   2   15  8
B   2006    9   2   12  11.2
B   2007    3   4   19  9.2
B   2007    6   3   19  8.6
B   2007    6   20  4   9.4
B   2007    7   3   2   10.2
B   2007    7   6   4   12.4
B   2007    7   16  17  8.6
B   2007    8   14  20  9
B   2008    1   21  10  9.2
B   2008    7   29  7   12
B   2008    8   1   2   11.8
B   2009    6   23  15  11.6
B   2009    7   1   14  10.6
B   2009    7   17  10  8.6
B   2010    8   7   17  12.2
B   2010    12  28  14  10.6
B   2011    6   19  6   8.2
B   2011    9   16  17  7.8
C   1992    1   5   13  8.8
C   1994    7   31  21  8.6
C   1994    8   4   4   9.2
C   1994    8   23  6   8.2
C   1995    7   17  4   11.4
C   1996    2   12  2   7.4
C   1996    4   23  5   7.8
C   1996    8   23  19  10.6
C   1996    9   26  22  9.6
C   1997    5   5   7   15.2
C   1997    11  16  16  7.8
C   1997    12  9   17  10.4
C   1998    1   8   10  8.2
C   1999    8   25  17  8.2
C   2000    6   3   21  7.8
C   2000    6   4   1   7.8
C   2000    7   31  12  7.6
C   2000    9   11  20  15.6
C   2001    6   14  17  8.2
C   2002    6   10  6   9
C   2002    6   14  17  9.4
C   2002    7   30  18  8
C   2002    8   2   6   7.6
C   2003    6   17  3   10.6
C   2004    6   23  4   7.6
C   2004    8   9   18  12.6
C   2004    8   10  8   13.8
C   2004    10  21  20  14
C   2005    4   26  18  10.2
C   2005    5   2   20  12
C   2006    4   1   2   7.6
C   2006    9   14  10  8.4
C   2007    6   20  4   9.4
C   2007    7   3   3   13
C   2007    7   16  19  17.6
C   2007    7   18  10  7.8
C   2007    7   26  14  19.2
C   2007    8   12  5   8.2
C   2007    8   14  18  12.6
C   2007    11  30  17  9.4
C   2008    5   28  19  7.6
C   2008    7   3   17  10
C   2008    7   5   15  25
C   2008    7   9   23  8.4
C   2008    7   11  9   8.6
C   2008    7   29  7   11.2
C   2008    8   1   3   13.8
C   2008    8   7   1   7.4
C   2008    12  5   15  17.2
C   2009    6   15  17  11
C   2009    11  1   10  8.4
C   2009    12  27  1   14.6
C   2010    6   29  3   9.4
C   2010    7   20  16  12
C   2010    12  28  11  9.4
C   2011    7   7   20  8.2
C   2011    8   11  5   9.4
C   2011    9   6   8   7.8
D   1994    6   13  17  11.1
D   1994    7   16  18  20
D   1994    7   31  20  10.6
D   1994    8   22  18  13
D   1994    8   23  6   9
D   1995    6   28  18  48
D   1995    7   10  15  20.3
D   1995    7   12  14  23
D   1995    7   26  12  32
D   1995    7   31  11  8.8
D   1995    8   1   20  41
D   1995    8   8   14  12.3
D   1995    8   17  14  31
D   1995    8   19  16  34
D   1996    6   14  14  18.7
D   1996    7   7   19  9.1
D   1996    8   26  19  9
D   1997    7   19  21  17
D   1997    7   20  12  17
D   1998    10  24  14  8.8
D   1999    5   7   20  12.1
D   1999    8   1   18  12.1
D   1999    10  1   10  8.8
D   2000    6   3   24  11.1
D   2002    6   14  18  17.6
D   2002    7   30  15  9.8
D   2004    6   23  4   11.1
D   2005    4   14  15  8.8
D   2005    5   21  18  13.3
D   2005    8   31  17  10.1
D   2006    8   16  22  20
D   2006    8   27  23  9
D   2006    9   2   12  13.6
D   2006    9   11  21  10.1
D   2006    9   14  15  16.7
D   2006    10  19  6   13.3
D   2006    10  25  18  11.6
D   2007    6   18  22  9.1
D   2007    6   19  22  10.1
D   2007    6   20  3   9.3
D   2008    7   11  18  9.1
D   2008    8   1   2   9
D   2008    8   20  22  9.6
E   1992    8   8   15  8.6
E   1992    8   9   6   7.4
E   1993    6   6   11  10.3
E   1993    8   4   24  8.3
E   1993    9   9   15  7.4
E   1993    10  5   17  7.8
E   1995    9   7   9   8.3
E   1996    8   27  14  13
E   1997    5   17  13  8.1
E   1997    7   2   20  7.4
E   1998    4   27  20  8.8
E   1998    10  27  9   12.3
E   2000    6   4   3   7.5
E   2000    11  2   17  11.8
E   2002    7   20  15  9.3
E   2002    7   30  17  7.4
E   2003    7   17  20  13
E   2003    8   11  11  8.1
E   2004    8   12  12  9.1
E   2005    6   19  17  16.3
E   2005    7   28  17  11
E   2005    8   12  3   10.3
E   2006    12  30  2   7.4
E   2007    6   15  9   9.1
E   2007    10  9   8   7.8
E   2008    8   7   6   14
E   2008    8   17  6   8.1
E   2009    6   6   4   7.8
E   2009    7   17  7   13.8
E   2009    11  1   11  7.8
E   2010    10  3   13  10.6
E   2011    7   16  13  7.4
E   2011    9   16  19  7.4
E   2011    11  3   17  7.5
F   1993    10  2   2   8.3
F   1995    9   7   23  11.3
F   1995    9   8   8   14.8
F   1996    6   2   12  13.3
F   1996    8   6   17  8.8
F   1996    8   28  8   9.8
F   1997    8   31  16  9.8
F   1998    7   31  19  8.3
F   1999    9   22  20  9.8
F   2000    8   3   13  14
F   2001    6   15  15  19.3
F   2002    6   14  18  11.6
F   2002    7   30  16  8.8
F   2002    8   1   23  26
F   2002    8   2   6   10.6
F   2003    7   25  14  10.1
F   2003    8   10  10  25.2
F   2003    9   19  22  8.8
F   2005    7   28  17  8.8
F   2006    9   14  17  11.3
F   2007    6   15  6   11.1
F   2008    3   29  20  9.6
F   2008    7   31  17  9
F   2008    8   1   5   8.6
F   2008    9   7   3   9.1
F   2009    7   3   12  8.6
F   2009    7   17  7   10.1
F   2009    7   29  15  10.6
F   2009    11  1   11  8.3
F   2010    7   20  16  11.6
G   1993    6   10  1   8.6
G   1993    7   15  20  8.1
G   1993    10  2   1   9.8
G   1995    7   13  20  10.8
G   1995    9   7   23  8.1
G   1996    8   6   16  17.6
G   1996    8   7   1   14.1
G   1996    8   23  18  10
G   1999    6   2   16  10.1
G   1999    6   27  16  9.3
G   2000    6   4   2   12.6
G   2000    7   2   4   8.3
G   2001    9   27  18  9.6
G   2003    5   2   18  8.1
G   2003    8   11  11  9.8
G   2004    7   30  15  9
G   2004    8   9   20  9.8
G   2005    7   28  18  16.6
G   2006    8   1   17  8.3
G   2006    8   18  16  8.8
G   2006    8   23  17  14.8
G   2006    9   14  15  8.3
G   2007    6   23  10  8.6
G   2008    8   17  3   10.1
G   2009    6   23  14  15.6
G   2009    7   3   12  9.1
G   2009    7   6   19  20.7
G   2009    7   17  7   12.6
G   2010    9   7   19  11.6
```